# Python if key in kwargs and key is true

Tags: python, conditional-statements, dictionary

```
if 'force' in kwargs and kwargs['force'] is True:
```

It feels like there should be a better way of writing this condition since I'm repeating both the key and variable.

Comment: `if kwargs.get('force', False):`, maybe? (documentation on `get` here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen No, because `kwargs.get('force', False)` will return `False` if `'force'` is found in `kwargs`.

Comment: No, it just returns `False` if 'force' is NOT in kwargs. `{'a':'b'}.get('a', False)` returns `'b'`, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [@EmanuelePaolini](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50391/emanuele-paolini) provided a great answer, there's another thing that I want to nitpick. You don't need to to check if something is true. For example, your code block would become this:

```
if 'force' in kwargs and kwargs['force']:
```

And [@EmanuelePaolini's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50391/emanuele-paolini) solution would become this:

```
if kwargs.get('force'):
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP doesn't need to check if something is True? The code you propose is not equivalent to the one provided by the OP.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini The OP is explicitly checking if `kwargs["force"]` is `True`, so it can be shortened.

Comment: If kwargs['force'] == 1 the condition kwargs['force'] is satisfied while (kwargs['force'] is True) is not satisfied.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you really do want to check if the returned keyword argument `is True`, here's another slightly different way:

```
if kwargs.get('force', False) is True:
```

I think adding the `False` argument is a little bit more explicit/clear to the reader.

Using the above, EVERY value returned by the `get` method will cause the clause to be skipped except for when it contains a value of `True`.

However, Python is very nice when it comes to type casting to boolean - very often it simply isn't necessary to explicitly check `is True`. If this is the case, you can simply do this:

```
if kwargs.get('force', False):
```

Doing it this way, the statement reduces to `if False` in only a handful of cases. Here are some of them (possibly not all - though [the docs says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) this covers all of them):

- `False`
- `None` - Python's null value
- `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `set()` - an empty container like a `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, or `set`
- `''` or `""` - an empty string
- `0`, `0.0` - any numerical that is equivalent to zero
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value `False`.

In this case, EVERY value returned by the `get` method will cause the clause to be executed except for when it contains a value that evaluates to `False`, such as one of the examples above. Any other value will evaluate to `True`. (Side note: containers that contain values which evaluate to `False` nonetheless evaluate to `True`, e.g., `[None, None]` or `(0, 0)` or `{False, False}`; this can be unexpected for inexperienced Python users).

If you want the key added to `kwargs` with a value of `False` at the point in time you check for it:

```
if kwargs.setdefault('force', False):
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the condition given by the OP. See comments on @Ethan Bierlein answer.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini  Technically, you're right. However, since OP has a high rep and this is the first question OP has ever asked tagged Python, I surmised that OP probably is an inexperienced Python user. Since checking for `is True` in Python is kind of unusual, I was extrapolating that what OP really wants to do is check it the usual way. I should be more explicit about this, though.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I edited to make my assumptions more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

A better way:

```
if kwargs.get('force') is True:
```

relies on the fact that `kwargs.get('force') is None` if `'force' not in kwargs'.`