# How to check if a kwarg is equal to a specific value

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

I have the following function:

```
def find_data(**data):  
    if data == 'price':
        ## do something
        print 'yes'
```

but when I call on the function below nothing happens:

```
  find_data(data='price')
```

My expected output is to have the function execute an operation when data = price (and for data = close , for example). I was wondering if there was a more pythonic , shorter way then:

```
def find_data(**data): 
    for k, v in data.items():
        if v == 'price':
             print 'yes'
```

Comment: `if data["data"] == "price"` would work

Comment: Is this considered the standard practice? (Thanks I like it its concise)

Comment: @thomas.mac The idiom (standard practice) is to name the variable for kwargs `kwargs` and then use it as a dictionary. That is its purpose.

Comment: @zxq9 Ok - so like you wrote in your answer ?

Comment: @thomas.mac Yep. Just like that. I think using these particular names are not just convention, but probably in a PEP somewhere as a specified practice. I'll add a reference if I find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python if key in kwargs and key is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683724/python-if-key-in-kwargs-and-key-is-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to reference kwargs as a dictionary.

Idiomatically:

```
def find_data(**kwargs):  
    if kwargs['data'] == 'price':
        ## do something
        print 'yes'
```

As an addendum... it is good to keep in mind that the more you know about the arguments coming into a function the less crazy hair your code will tend to grow over time (that is to say, the less polymorphism and variadism you engage in the clearer the semantics of your code will tend to be over time). So it is good to think carefully about whether you really need to pass in "just some random keyword args" or if you should be instead receiving a dictionary of a specific shape *as a single argument* or perhaps receiving that specific value as an explicit argument of its own.

Answer (score 1):

you're mixing up keyword argument with parameter dictionary.

In `find_data`, `data` is the dictionary of the keyword arguments (ill-named, as it's usually called `kwargs`). Comparing `data` to a string doesn't work (not the same types). You want:

```
def find_data(**data):
    if data["data"] == 'price':
        ## do something
        print('yes')

find_data(data="price")
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't get the downvote -- because technically you are correct. But then again, maybe its because a few variables in Python have standard names by convention like `self`, `args` and `kwargs`. ?

Comment: yes, I was explaining the confusion. my explanation is probably clumsy. And the downvote is from python DV police: hi-rep user answering "trivial" questions not perfectly as it should. well, sc**w them.

Comment: Wow. Yeah. I had totally forgotten about the joykill police corps here on SO. This is why I answer questions pretty much exclusively for Erlang, Postgres, Mercury and a few other less mainstream langs/frameworks. *Every* time I engage in Python or Java or other mainstream langs here I get turned off by the presence of SO cops.

Comment: it depends. But on pure python (without any file/csv/compression packages) it can be hash sometimes.